# Intent.getType() returning null in onNewIntent(Intent intent ) method

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to get Intent of mime type **text/plain** from other apps and store that text in a variable of type string. It is working fine from **onCreate** method but when i uses **singleTask** as launchmode and pause the app(by pressing home button) and try to share text from other app to my app, **onNewIntent(Intent intent)** method is getting called and **intent.getType()** is returning null,but same is working fine from **onCreate** method, I don't know why, please help. Thanks

```
private String sharedData="";
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {

    intent = getIntent();
    String action = intent.getAction();

    String type = intent.getType();  //this method is returning null

    if(intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action) && type!=null)
    {
        sharedData = FileHandler.handleSendText(intent);//FileHandler is class i created with contains method handleSendText
    }

    super.onNewIntent(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call `intent = getIntent();` will return you the original `intent` provided to the activity. Hence, it should be null. Try removing this line.

Comment: Yes it is working, what do you mean by original intent? please can you explain more? Thanks

Comment: Whenever an activity is started a new intent is provided to it which you can get via `getIntent()` which is basically initialized when the app is first launched. In your case since, you are getting the call in `onNewIntent()`, the updated intent should be the one provided in method arguments only and not via `getIntent()`.

Comment: Make sense. Thanks.

Comment: Cool...if you feel satisfied, you may want to 'accept' this answer